# Joining two tables by two columns where the data types don't match

Tags: mysql, casting

I am trying to join two tables of a MySQL database one two columns:

```
SELECT ol.utdate, ol.session, dl.utdate, dl.dsession FROM observation_log ol 
LEFT OUTER JOIN diary_log dl ON (ol.utdate = dl.utdate AND ol.session = dl.dsession);
```

The trouble is ol.session is a CHAR and dl.dsession is a TINYINT(4). The correspondence between the two is integers for letters in the alphabet:

```
=======================
ol.session||dl.dsession
=======================
A         ||1
B         ||2
C         ||3
...
=======================
```

How can I convert (map or cast, not sure the correct verb to use here) either ol.session or dl.dsession to either both be a letter or an integer?

Thanks,
Aina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [`ASCII()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii) function to convert upper case letters from the `ol.session` column to numbers which should match the `dl.session` column:

```
SELECT
    ol.utdate,
    ol.session,
    dl.utdate,
    dl.dsession
FROM observation_log ol 
LEFT OUTER JOIN diary_log dl
    ON ol.utdate = ol.utdate AND
       ASCII(ol.session) - 64 = dl.dsession
```

Note that `ASCII('A')` returns 65, with `ASCII('B')` returning 66, and so on.  So if we subtract `64` from `ASCII(ol.session)` we can bring things into alignment.

Comment: Tim, it works EXACTLY as advertised, thanks! I'll accept the answer once the website lets me. Thank you!!!